# Well pump not running and busted hose

Tags: water, well, well-pump

Water well pump is not pumping any water to the house. Just checked the well house and noticed large hose has busted.
What do I do?

Comment: If that's the level of detail you can or will provide to ask for help, "call a well guy" is probably the right answer. You need to [edit] in a lot more details, pictures, etc. to have any hope of anyone being able to answer in detail. Turn power to the pump off, repair the hose, probably quite a few more steps past that.

Comment: "No water at the house pump is not running busted line at well house what do I do"  answer:  Fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the hose.

Most places with hardware/plumbing departments will have the parts needed.

Take a section of the hose with you to get the right sizes.